# Getting coordinate of view with relative to parent ScrollView

Tags: android

Previously, I have the following `ScrollView` and layout. Its *scroll till selected view visible* code works.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <Info View 1/>
        <Info View 2/>
        <Info View 3/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

private void initScrollView() {
    if (this.selectedInfoView == null) {
        // Nothing to scroll.
        return;
    }

    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

    Rect rect = new Rect();
    Rect scrollViewRect = new Rect();
    selectedInfoView.getHitRect(rect);
    scrollView.getDrawingRect(scrollViewRect);
    int dy = rect.bottom - scrollViewRect.bottom;
    if (dy > 0) {
        scrollView.scrollBy(0, dy);
    }
}
```

Note, `getHitRect` will return the coordinate respect to one level up parent. So, the above code will work.

However, when comes to slightly complicated case. The above code no longer work.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout 0>
        <TextView/>
        <LinearLayout 1>
            <Info View 1/>
            <Info View 2/>
            <Info View 3/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView/>
        <LinearLayout 2>
            <Info View 4/>
            <Info View 5/>
            <Info View 6/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In my code, if I encounter *Info View 1 - 3*, I need to take consideration into *LinearLayout 0* and *LinearLayout 1*'s `getHitRect`. When comes to *Info View 4 - 6*, I need to take consideration into *LinearLayout 0* and *LinearLayout 2*'s `getHitRect`.

Things look cumbersome. Is there any way for me to obtain the coordinate of a view, relative to top most `ScrollView`?

Comment: Does the `ScrollView` fill the entire screen?

Comment: Yes in term of height. It is being used as sliding menu

Comment: I'm not sure about this but did you looked at the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow%28int[]%29 method?

Comment: I tried. But not 100% working. I post my finding as 1 of the answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the currently workable code. Is cumbersome. But it works at this moment. I have a few observations.

```
private void initScrollView() {
    if (this.selectedInfoView == null) {
        // Nothing to scroll.
        return;
    }

    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = null;

    if (this.selectedInfo instanceof Info0) {
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.linearLayout0);
    } else {
        assert(this.selectedInfo instanceof Info1);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    }

    Rect rect = new Rect();
    Rect linearLayoutRect = new Rect();
    Rect scrollViewRect = new Rect();
    selectedInfoView.getHitRect(rect);
    linearLayout.getHitRect(linearLayoutRect);
    scrollView.getDrawingRect(scrollViewRect);

    // Get coordinate relative to linear layout. See the note below.
    int correct_expected_bottom_y = linearLayoutRect.top + rect.bottom;

    int dy = correct_expected_bottom_y  - scrollViewRect.bottom;
    if (dy > 0) {
        scrollView.scrollBy(0, dy);
    }
}
```

I also tested with `getLocationInWindow`, `getLocationOnScreen` and `getLocalVisibleRect`. None of them fool proof.

(x, y - width, height)

```
--------------------
|                  | (?, 120) <-- correct expected bottom y
|                  | (0, 146) <-- from getLocationInWindow/ getLocationOnScreen
|                  | (0, 0 - 360, 72) <-- from getLocalVisibleRect
--------------------
|                  | (?, 193) <-- correct expected bottom y
|                  | (0, 219) <-- from getLocationInWindow/ getLocationOnScreen
|                  | (0, 0 - 360, 72) <-- from getLocalVisibleRect
--------------------
|                  | (?, 266) <-- correct expected bottom y
|                  | (0, 292) <-- from getLocationInWindow/ getLocationOnScreen
|                  | (0, 0 - 360, 72) <-- from getLocalVisibleRect
--------------------
|                  | (?, 339) <-- correct expected bottom y
|                  | (0, 365) <-- from getLocationInWindow/ getLocationOnScreen
|                  | (0, 0 - 360, 72) <-- from getLocalVisibleRect
--------------------
|                  | (?, 485) <-- correct expected bottom y
| [not visible]    | (0, 511) <-- from getLocationInWindow/ getLocationOnScreen
|                  | (0, 413 - 360, 485) <-- from getLocalVisibleRect
--------------------
```

### getLocationInWindow

It always have 26 more pixels than the expected value. For example, take the first row, *26 = 146 - 120*. I think that might be contributed by `ActionBar`, or `StatusBar` height.

### getLocationOnScreen

Same behavior as `getLocationInWindow`

### getLocalVisibleRect

It only get same value as expected value, when the row is completely not visible on screen. Not sure why. Look at the last row, where it is having same bottom y value (485) as expected bottom y.

Comment: I guess the location in window also counts for the status bar but you could easily offset the received position by checking the difference betwen the location in window of the target view and the location in window of the `ScrollView` resulting in the position of the view in the `ScrollView`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this was available in 2013, you can do this now like this:

```
val bounds = Rect()
childView.getDrawingRect(bounds) // now bounds has the visible drawing coordinates of the view
parentViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(childView, bounds) // now bounds has the view's coordinates according to the parentViewGroup
```

`parentViewGroup` is a parent of the `childView` in any level in the hierarchy.